# Load nodes into Neo4j from CSV according to their id?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following CSV:

```
id  attr   value
1   abc    1.1    
1   eww    -9.4  
1   ssv    likj
2   we2    1 
2   eww   900  
3   kuku   -91  
3   lulu   383
3   ssv    bubu
```

I would like to create 3 nodes that consists of:

```
Node 1: {id:1, abc: 1.1, eww: -9.4, ssv: "likj"}
Node 2: {id:2, we2: 1, eww: 900}
Node 3: {id:3, kuku: -91, lulu: 383, ssv: "bubu"}
```

How can I build it in Neo4j cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have found the [documentation about LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) , so I'll skip that. AND I am assuming that the nodes will have a `MyThing` label , and that `id` is a property, so not the internal Neo4j id.

Before doing the import, create a constraint:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:MyLabel) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE
```

You also may want to install the apoc plugin, because it has a bunch a very nice functions in it for cases like this.

then, something like this:

```
LOAD CSV ..  AS line

WITH line.id AS id, 
     COLLECT([line.attr,line.value]) AS keyValuePairs
WITH id,
     apoc.map.fromPairs(keyValuePairs) AS map

MERGE (n:MyLabel {id:id})
SET n += map
```

Comment: When you say ```with line.id as id, ... collect```, does it mean "groupby" by id and then collect? @graphileon

Comment: Yes. That’s how aggregation functions in cypher work.

Comment: Just a word of caution. Nothing wrong with your strategy, but id also refers to Neo4j's internal identifier of nodes and relationships which you cannot control. You do call on it in a distinct manner to avoid problem. Nonetheless, I use an unambiguous id, such as place_id.

Comment: I don’t think there is ambiguity. Internal ids are referred to as id(n) , not as n.id   I agree with you that you should not use internal ids in communication with other systems.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, I do get the nodes but the only property I have there is the id, and it's not the id I need @graphileon

Comment: Do you mean that you want the data in your csv to be merged into existing nodes?

Comment: @Graphileon can you please advise how to include the original id inside every node I have created?